# Only use first word using .text()

Tags: jquery

I have a subnav which I am using the text in the subnav to reference a class of the DIV element.

some of the subnav text has spaces so for the ones that have spaces I just want to use the first word only to reference the class of the DIV element.

SCRIPT

```
$('li.' + $(this).text( function () {

if space

   take first letter only.toggle(true);

if no space

   do nothing.toggle(true);

});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>all</li>
<li>men</li>
<li>women</li>
<li>sun protective clothing</li>
</ul>
<div class="men"></div>
<div class="women"></div>
<div class="sun"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean 'first __word__' instead of 'first __letter__'?

Comment: use split. pretty basic javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the javascript string split method : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var className = $(this).text().split(' ')[0];
```

Comment: @jason , just asking casually why everyone on this site hates w3schools, for beginers its pretty good right

Comment: It's simply the first link in the Google search 'javascript array split'. Instead of linking to a page that doesn't like w3schools, why not link to an alternative? (PS I don't really like them that much either but as a basic javascript reference for when you really can't remember the syntax they're fine).

Comment: @kobe and everyone else, please go to the w3fools site and read what it has to say about why posting to w3schools is DANGEROUS. a short synopsis is that they are often INCORRECT with what they post and often times MISLEADING with their information.